# I would be happy to pay real money for succesful solution to my question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been using unix.stackexchange.com for almost 2 years, and during the time, I have asked more than 200 questions.

Thanks to SE, I have solved problems that I could not have solved on my own. I have often relied on "bounty" to draw attention to a problem that was particularly important to me. But still, some of my questions/problems remain unsolved to this day.

I understand that perhaps they are to specific that not enough people care.

I would be happy to pay real $$$ for a solution, but AFAIK this is not possible on this site. Are there any plans for paying real money on SE sites ?

Comment: See [Offering actual money as a bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty) on the main meta

Comment: You want an actual contracting site ([e.g.](https://www.elance.com/p/lpg/programming/programmers-hire)).  They hold the money in escrow until you get what you asked for, etc.

Comment: @goldilocks - I have tried `guru.com` and `freelancer.com`, but these sites work completely differently.

Answer (score 7):

Not as far as I know,  no.  That's not what SE is about.  There are many sites out there that help you hire programmers,  we just do Q&A.

There have been similar proposals on the main meta which have always been turned down. Adding money to the SE model would just result in loads of unanswered questions since people would go for the ones they get paid for. It would also create a business relationship between the asker and whoever answers,  allowing the OP to feel entitled to an answer.  Not to mention, the huge legal complications involved with the transfer of services for money.

So,  in short,  no there are no such plans and I fervently hope there never will be. Personally,  I would stop participating if this became a paid service.

Comment: You mean it is not true that every rep point gets you one USD, and every time you reach a multiple of 25K reputation you get a check in the mail? Darn, I just thought my check was taking a bit in the mail from the US, of course I already spent the money...

Comment: @Anthon shhhhhh! No one under 10k rep is supposed to know that!

Answer (score 5):

I hope not.

Commericalising this community, or any of the other places around the Internet where people who believe in free and open source software give their time to help others, would have nothing but a deleterious effect. Not everything of value can and should be reduced to a cash transaction (or, in the words of growth hackers, "monetised").

If you want to pay a developer to help you, there are plenty of ways to do that. Turning this site into a marketplace isn't one of them.